# A question on finite dimensional space of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let f be a infinitely differentiable function: $ f: R \rightarrow C$ ; $ f\in C^{\infty}$.

We define: $ f_a : x \rightarrow f(x+a) $ the translated function of a .

Now let's define : $ E = Vect( f_a , a\in R ) $ , that is the space generated by all $f_a$ functions.

**Hypothesis:** E is of finite dimension.

**Question:** characterize the functions f that make this hypothesis true.

Now I do have a tricky solution to answer this, but I'd like to know how you would respond to such a question, because I think there might be very different approach and I don't want to orient anyone, especially because I don't find it intuitive. I will edit the question about my findings if you think it's necessary.

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you think such $f$ can be more than constant functions?

Comment: I know it's more than that, I've managed to prove it, but I don't want to spoil the pleasure :)

Comment: I don't know if it's clear, but f is a real variable function, and is complex valued (could be real valued, it's more general here and it doesn't change much). For instance, consider f: x-> $e^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any such $f$ is a linear combination of functions $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_N\}$ such that
$$
\phi_i(x+a)=\sum_{j=1}^N A_{i,j}\,\phi_j(x)
$$
for some $N\times N$ matrix $A=(A_{i,j})$. For example 
$$\begin{align}
(x+a)^i &=\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j}a^{i-j}x^j\\
e^{d(x+a)}&=e^{da}\,e^{dx}
\end{align}$$
The function $f$ can be

1. A polynomial of degree $N$: $\phi_i(x)=x^i$, $0\le i\le N$.
2. $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^N c_i\,e^{d_ix}$
3. A combination of the above

Comment: :) , how di you find it ?

Comment: Once you realize that $f(x+a)$ must be a linear combination of a finite number of $f(x+a_i)$ everything and think of some examples, it wasn't too difficult to get the solution.

Comment: Yes agreed, but to prove it I went into some trouble, especially because at some point I think you have to prove that a certain limit of functions of E is in E. The thing is I had to consider a point to point convergence (so not associated to any norm, it complicate things) and had to prove that each coefficient (a real sequence ) of the expansion of the sequence in the basis converges. I don't know if you see what I mean..

Comment: I'll accept your answer since nobody will be likely to contribute, but I knew the answer (found it myself) and I was in fact more interested in the proof itself. I don't know if you have found a simple one, but mine requires a bit of work. Thanks anyway though :)